# Node.js read file from temporary URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to read a text file that the user has previously selected with:

```
<input id="file" type="file" name="file" id="file" />
```

so I have defined a listener like this:

```
$('#file').change( function(event) {
    file = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
});
```

And After I need to copy it and I'm using a function to copy file like this:

```
function copyFile(source, target, cb) {
  var cbCalled = false;

  var rd = fs.createReadStream(source);
  rd.on("error", function(err) {
    done(err);
  });
  var wr = fs.createWriteStream(target);
  wr.on("error", function(err) {
    done(err);
  });
  wr.on("close", function(ex) {
    done();
  });
  rd.pipe(wr);

  function done(err) {
    if (!cbCalled) {
      cb(err);
      cbCalled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

But I have an error:
***Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'blob:file%3A///78a3eba0-4e94-4fed-8449-e66b676c92ad'***

How can I copy from the temporary URL the browser has created in memory?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You need to use ajax send the file to the server.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but why I need to create a server for that?, Can you explain why? everything is on the client machine, there is no reason to have a server. I tried also to get the full path of the uploaded file but I cannot (I'm using electron)

Comment: If you're using electron you already use node.js server.

Comment: Ok , thanks! I have done as you suggested and it works, I still haven't understood why we have to do this trick, in any case thanks!